# Consuming external webservice with ASP

Tags: web-services, asp-classic

I'm doing a simple page to register users. However after I get the user's input I need to call a web service to get a token which will then allow me to call another web service which will finally proceed to register the user (using the input AND the token).
So what I want to know is how to call this WS and retrieve it's response and then add that response (which would be the token) to the form used for user registration.

Edit: I'm using classic ASP

Comment: is this for classic asp or asp .net ??

Comment: Classic ASP, sorry I didn't know there was a difference

Comment: its ok i just asked because i thought it si for classic asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how the web service is written. These days most APIs are written using REST (i.e. standard HTTP GET/POST URL format). So you simply make a call to a URL, and get a value back - you can do this using ASP's "ServerXMLHTTP" component. e.g.

```
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xml.Open "POST", sURL, False
xml.Send parms
returnValue = xml.ResponseText
```

Then do something with "returnValue"